# Winform display bug

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface, gridview, datagridview

I've developed a Winform application 1 (or 2) year(s) ago, based on .NET Framework 4.5.

There are a few users experiencing a strange bug where a control group doesn't appear. I never succeded in reproducing the bug to fix it.
It occurs rarely. Out of ~200 users, only one is currently experiencing this issue.

Here is how it should be :
[image: notice the "Selected customer" UI control]

Here is how it is with the issue :
[image: The gridview overflows and only the checkbox "Show hidden customers" is visible]

Does someone have any suggestion ?

EDIT: In the first screenshot, you can see the "Selected customer" group control. When the user clicks on a row in the gridview, the related customer is displayed there and can click on the "Select this customer" button.

On the second screenshot, you can see that the gridview overflows till the bottom. The "selected customer" part isn't displayed. (but the checkbox "Show hidden customers" is still displayed)

This is the method which loads the gridview :

```
private void SetUpCustomersGridView()
    {
        if (chkbx_showHiddenCustomers.Checked)
        {
            dgv_customer.DataSource = _mySqlCeEngine.GetAllCustomers();
        }
        else
        {
            dgv_customer.DataSource = _mySqlCeEngine.GetVisibleCustomers();
        }

        gv_customer.Columns[0].Caption = "ID";
        gv_customer.Columns[1].Caption = "Name";
        gv_customer.Columns[2].Caption = "Address";
        gv_customer.Columns[3].Caption = "City";
        gv_customer.Columns[4].Caption = "Zip Code";
        gv_customer.Columns[5].Caption = "Country Code";
        gv_customer.Columns[6].Caption = "Cluster";
        gv_customer.Columns[7].Caption = "Magellan Party/Account/Site ID/Account Site ID";
        gv_customer.BestFitColumns();

        gv_customer.OptionsFilter.AllowFilterEditor = false;
        gv_customer.OptionsView.ShowAutoFilterRow = true;
        foreach (DevExpress.XtraGrid.Columns.GridColumn col in gv_customer.Columns)
        {
            col.OptionsFilter.AutoFilterCondition = DevExpress.XtraGrid.Columns.AutoFilterCondition.Contains;
        }
    }
```

And this, is the code which display the bottom part when a row is clicked :

```
private void gv_customer_RowClick(object sender, RowClickEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            DataRowView selectedRow = GetCustomersGridSelectedRow();
            if (selectedRow != null){ btn_selectCustomer.Enabled = true; }
            lbl_valueCustomerID.Text = GetCustomerID(selectedRow); 
            lbl_valueCustomerName.Text = GetCustomerName(selectedRow);
            lbl_valueCustomerAddress.Text = GetCustomerAddress(selectedRow);
            lbl_valueCustomerCity.Text = GetCustomerCity(selectedRow);
            lbl_valueCustomerZipCode.Text = GetCustomerZipCode(selectedRow);
            lbl_valueCustomerCountry.Text = GetCustomerCountryCode(selectedRow);
        }
        catch{}
    }
```

EDIT2: New info from the user-> when running the app in safe mode, everything is fine..

Thanks,

Hellcat8

Comment: What is the issue?  Can't tell from the screenshots.

Comment: Sorry i forgot that part. I edited my post, thanks.

Comment: Only someone looking at the source code can suggest a fix for that.

Comment: Yes, I'm getting the source code. I'll edit my post as soon as I got the source.

Comment: An empty try-catch isn't helping you see if something went wrong.

Comment: I removed the code inside to make it shorter.

Comment: Is it possibly a Z-Ordering issue where the Customer Info panel is behind the GridView (assuming GridView is set to Dock.Fill) ?

Comment: i see, you're using the DevExpress controls. Have you tried to contact support team?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a race condition to me. Is the display of the missing control dependent on some data being loaded in the data grid? If so, the data not being loaded could cause the loading of the subsequent control to fail.

Could you post the code that loads the form?

You may be able to use async / await to only execute the dependent form logic once the DataGrid has finished loading.

Comment: The part missing depends on nothing to be displayed. It's just a table on a panel, with labels. But when the user clicks on a row in the gridview above, it populates data from gridview to invisibles labels (default state) below.